# PayPal statement via API

Tags: paypal

I have just reviewed REST API and Classic API references and there doesn't seem to be a method which would allow to obtain transactions statement? Essentially I am looking for what can be found in PayPal admin panel under History -> Download History -> Balance Affecting Payment.

Any suggestions how to obtain PayPal statement via API very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an API for this.  However, a couple of options would be to use IPN and have all of the data written to your own database, and then you can query your own database for the information.  Another option would be to sign up for SFTP reporting on your account.  Then you can connect via SFTP and retrieve reports.